# data() for a class selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this line in my code:

```
$(".view" + nodeID).data("urls",viewURLs);
```

(nodeID is a variable I increment for each element)
After that, another element with the same class is added to the DOM.
And later on, I have:

```
alert($(".view" + nodeID).data("urls"));
```

Which for some reason, displays "undefined".
Now my question is: Could it be related to the fact that I added another element with the same class? Does it override the data? I'd expect jQuery to retain data for a class selector, even if its satisfying elements changed. Or am I missing something in the way selectors work?
Thanks.

More details: When I set the data, nodeID contains a number which increases each time. Later, on a click event, the ID is extracted from a string that contains it and used in the expression to get the data:

```
var nodeElement=$(this).closest("table");
if (nodeElement==null) return;
var nodeFullID=nodeElement.attr("id");
var separatorIndex=nodeFullID.indexOf("-");
if (separatorIndex==-1) return;
var nodeID=nodeFullID.substring(4,separatorIndex);
alert($(".view" + nodeID).data("urls"));
```

Could it be related to the fact that to set the data, nodeID is treated as a number, and then joined to a string to compose the selector, and to get the data, nodeID is extracted from a string?

Comment: Maybe you should show more of your code. It probably has something to do with your `nodeID`

Comment: use `attr('data-urls')` instead. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr#7262427

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: attr(data-urls) is only for HTML5, I don't want to limit the page. And yes, it reproduces every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption

> I'd expect jQuery to retain data for a class selector

is unfortunately wrong. The data is stored on an element-base and not on a selector-base. So:

```
$(".view" + nodeID).data("urls",viewURLs);
```

Will set that data on all **elements** within the result-set of `$(".view" + nodeID)`. When adding new elements to the DOM, those elements wont (magically) have that data stored.

When executing

```
$(".view" + nodeID).data("urls")
```

jQuery will return the data of the **first element** in the result-set. If that happens to be your newly added element, the result will be `undefined`. As per [manual](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2):

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection

Well, that's what is going wrong. Possible solutions are

A) Have a variable within your code that stores the `urls` per `nodeID`:

```
// Define it somewhere
var urlsPerNode = {};
// Add it somewhere
urlsPerNode[ nodeID ] = urls;
// And debug it
alert(urlsPerNode[ nodeID ]);
```

Remember that the variable should be in scope everywhere you want to access it.

B) Store the `data("urls", viewURLs)` **everytime** you add a new element to the DOM. Storing it only to that new element is sufficient enough

```
var newElement = ...; // your logic
$(newElement).data("urls", viewURLs);
```

By the way, if your `.view + nodeID` is the table in your given code, you can simply read it out by:

```
alert( $(this).closest("table").data("urls") );
```

as jQuery stores the data on the element, and not on the used selector.